# Using SP_Admin account, can I sign in on behalf of another user?

Tags: 2010, user, sign-in, on-behalf

When we get reports of error from users it's sometimes hard to know what actually happened. The error report from the user may not be as descriptive as you would wish and it would be easier if you saw the error yourself.

This is especially true if you work as a consultant on remote. So it would help a lot if there where a way to sign on behalf of that user reporting the error and see what happens and also have the option to read error logs as they happen.

**Is it possible using the SP_Admin account to sign in on behalf of another user?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An admin account cannot impersonate another user account as far as I know.  In the environments I work in, I have asked for a few dummy or test accounts to be set up. In a problem situation, I'll assign the dummy account the same permissions as the user experiencing the problem and then log in with the dummy account to see the user experience.

Comment: I do the same thing - and my dummy account works perfect. But the user still claim that his account doesnt work. The problem is I can't verify that without signing in on behalf of the other user. Thanks for your input!

Comment: how about hooking up a GotoMeeting session (or similar) and letting the user share their screen while they do what they do? You can then direct them and follow exactly what they are doing.

Comment: That's of course another option that I'm trying to avoid. But it's the *last chance saloon* - as I want to follow up with ULS-logs as well.